# Background thread lambda callback

Tags: c#

At the moment when my background thread is complete it runs a System.Action callback using an anonymous lambda statement. I'm wondering how can I rewrite the code below to have a callback/lambda statement using a Completed function.

ViewModel : BaseViewModel

```
public override void Initialize(System.Action onInitializeCallback = null)
{.....
    BackgroundEntityWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        If (onInitializeCallback != null)
        {
            onInitializeCallback();
        }    
    };
.....
}
```

I want to change it to something below

```
BackgroundEntityWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_Completed =>
{
    If (onInitializeCallback != null)
    {
        onInitializeCallback();
    }    
};
```

BaseViewModel

```
public virtual void Reload(int? id = null, Action<T> callback = null)
{    
    Initialize(() =>
    {
        Localize();

        if (id == null)
        {
            IndicateLoading(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Load(id.Value, () => IndicateLoading(false));
        }
    });
}
```

I get an error `Argument type 'Lambda expression` is not assignable to parameter type `System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`

I tried

```
BackgroundEntityWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_Completed;
```

but I lose my callback, how do I set it to have BackGroundWorker_Completed and maintain my callback?

Comment: You lost me.  You're trying to send it two callback functions...sort of.  I don't get what you want.

Comment: Are you trying to use a named method as your callback? At the moment I'm not sure what you mean by "have a callback/lambda statement using a Completed function" and your example doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Just pass the delegate you intend to use.  Replace the entire lambda with the name of the delete (your other callback function).

Comment: What is `BackgroundWorker_Completed`? That's the thing the compiler error is referring to.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to set the thread completed to my Backgroundworker_Completed and maintain my callback as well.

Comment: Why don't you just use async await instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
BackgroundEntityWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    If (onInitializeCallback != null)
    {
        onInitializeCallback();
    }    
}
```

but careful about `BackgroundEntityWorker` null access

```
public override void Initialize(System.Action onInitializeCallback = null)
{   
        If (BackgroundEntityWorker.RunWorkerCompleted != null)
        {
            BackgroundEntityWorker.RunWorkerCompleted();
        }    
}
```

You are redirecting twice the event. It would be easier for us, if you show how your complete event raising